# Tikz Circle Divided into Quadrants

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, circles

I'm trying to create a circle, divided into four quadrants by a dashed "cross", where the top slice is slightly smaller than the bottom slice. I want to label the four quadrants with labels `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` (centered inside the quadrants), as well as label the top and bottom slices.

Here is my first attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[dashed] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
\draw[dashed] (0,2) -- (0,-2);
\draw (0,1.5) node{Top Piece};
\draw (0,-0.5) node{Bottom Piece};
\draw (-1,1.5) node{$a$};
\draw (1,1.5) node{$b$};
\draw (-1,-0.5) node{$c$};
\draw (1,-0.5) node{$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However it has at least a few problems:

1. It is coordinate-based, which means it doesn't scale. If I want to make my circle bigger (and I am thinking bigger would be a good idea), I would have to redraw all the lines and nodes and labels to fit the new circle;
2. The lines and circle don't intersect exactly, only approximately, which may be a consequence of #1;
3. The vertical dashed line cuts through the labels "top piece" and "bottom piece".

Should I go about creating this circle a different way? Please pardon my beginner's knowledge of Tikz. And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text can not be scaled, consequently it can happens that at scaling which shrink the picture texts will overlapping.  A possible solution is that texts `a`, `top pieces` and `b` merge in one node. Nodes with `fill` will hide dashed lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}%for showing just a picture
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
every node/.style = {inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=1mm, fill=white}
                    ]
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[densely dashed]   
    (150:2) -- (30:2)       (270:2) -- (90:2);
\draw (0,1.4) node[fill=white]{a Top Piece b};
\draw (0,-0.5) node[fill=white]{c\quad Bottom Piece\quad d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

With `scale=2` you obtain scaled pictures, but size of nodes stay the same.

[image]

Comment: Could you use the `relsize` package to scale the text as well, using a macro for the scale factors?

Comment: Of course :-), but what you like to achieve with it? Change the size of fonts? If you use it, the macro should be placed before `tikzpicture`, for example: `\relsize{3}\begin{tikzpucture}[ .... <options> ...]`. Matter of taste.

Comment: @Zarko You can use `scale=2,transform shape,` to also scale the font size.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, thank you to pointed me to this possibilities. I was consider, that this is not what OP wish. When the scale is large, the text can become -- this is my opinion of course -- to large and picture becomes ugly.

Comment: Thanks so much @Zarko ! Is it possible to center the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` text in the center of the four quadrants?

Comment: @AthanAlvare, remembering basics of geometry help me to determine points on circle (by help of definition points on cyrle by polar coordinates /`angle:distance'/. Putting labels in center of coordinates need little more effort, but then can happen, that they will be covered with other text.